# Send data from one WP instance to another and process it there

Tags: multisite, rest-api, migration

I am looking for a good way to send data from one WordPress to another.

Setup:
WP1: Frontend, form to submit data.
WP2: Backend, receives data and processes it.

So in WP1 users just use a form to submit data.
This data should be transferred to WP2. In WP2 the data is being processed (Custom Posts are created, post meta is being added, a user is created ...).

How can I submit all the data from WP1 to WP2?

I thought about using a GET request to "forward" the form data from WP1 to WP2.

Another way could be to use the REST API to transfer the data - but I struggle with that because the processing should happen at WP2 not at WP1.

Can you help me with what is the best way to simply send the form data and trigger processing at WP2?

Comment: to do that you can create a new endpoint on the REST API of WP2 and then on WP1 you call this endpoint and send the datas https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/

Comment: Thank you, that looks good! I'm just reading through the docs....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with mmm's hint and created a simple custom REST endpoint.

WP1 (Frontend, sending the data):

```
function send_form_data_to_backend($form_values) {

    // add secret-key
    $form_values['secret_key'] = "abcde123";

    $url = 'http://backend.example.com/wp-json/example/v1/save/';
    $response = wp_safe_remote_post( $url, array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'timeout' => 15,
        'redirection' => 5,
        'blocking' => true,
        'headers' => array(),
        'body' => $form_values,
        'cookies' => array()
        )
    );

    if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
       $error_message = $response->get_error_message();
       echo "Something went wrong: $error_message";
    } else {
       echo 'Response:<pre>';
       print_r( $response );
       echo '</pre>';
    }
}
```

WP2 (Backend, receiving the data):

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'post_request' );

function post_request() {

    register_rest_route( 'example/v1', '/save/', array(
                'methods' => 'POST',
                'callback' => 'rest_function')
    );
}


/*
 * REST Function
 */
function rest_function( $data ) {

    if ( $data['secret_key'] == "abcde123" ) {

        $msg = example_main_form_processing( $data );

        return $msg;

    } else {
        return "Wrong Key.";
    }

}
```